# Royalty distribution negotiable?

Tags: patents

It seems many US academic institutes co-own patents filed by their employees, and have policies for redistributing the royalty (minus costs) back to the inventor. For example,

- [Stanford](http://otl.stanford.edu/inventors/inventors_policies.html): 1/3
- [MIT](https://tlo.mit.edu/community/policies/part4#48): 1/3
- [University of California (UC)](http://www.ucop.edu/innovation-alliances-services/staff/financial-administration/inventor-share-policy.html) system: 35%
- [State University of New York (SUNY)](http://www.albany.edu/osp/24629.php) system: 40%

Are these numbers negotiable? In particular, can the academic institute force a lower proportion for inventor redistribution by making a deal with the inventor?

Comment: I'm not completely clear on the last part - do you want to know if the institute can force the inventor to accept a smaller percentage (less pay) than what their official published policy states (1)? Or do you want to know if you can possible negotiate a higher payment for yourself as inventor, in exchange for the institute taking a lower percentage (2)? In the first case, it seems like it would be easy to argue that the institute is trying to violate their own published policy and that would be bad faith, but would be a legal question.

Comment: @BrianDHall It could be either case. This is a hypothetical question. Not looking for a legal advice. Anecdotes would be helpful.